# set datetime object time value to 0

Tags: python

I need to set the time value of detatime objects to 00:00, so I can easily compare two 'dates'

Now I do:

```
extracted_start_date = datetime.strptime(extracted_start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

so I have my datetime object

```
$ datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 18, 11, 13, 53, 782088),
```

I extract the date string strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

```
$ '2021-03-18'
```

and put this back into a datetime object now wch has time 00:00

```
$ datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 18, 0, 0)
```

This seems quite elaborate, is there a more efficient way, or is it OK like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.datetime` objects have method `date` which return `datetime.date` instance and these might be used for day-based comparison, consider following example:

```
import datetime
d1 = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 17, 9, 0, 0)  # yesterday 9:00
d2 = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 18, 9, 0, 0)  # today 9:00
d3 = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 18, 12, 0, 0) # today 12:00
print(d1.date() == d2.date())
print(d2.date() == d3.date())
```

output:

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the replace method instead.

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime(2021, 3, 18, 11, 13, 53, 782088)
d.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
>  datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 18, 0, 0)
```